# Erase from vector

Tags: c++

I have these classes:

```
class PC
{
public:
    PC(string in_operatingSystem,int in_ramSlots,int in_pcieSlots,int in_totalRamSlots, int in_gbPerRam, int in_cpu, int in_ssd, int in_cost);

    virtual void Print() = 0;
    virtual void Upgrade() = 0;
protected:
    string operatingSystem;
    int ramSlots,pcieSlots,totalRamSlots,gbPerRam;
    int cpu,ssd;
    int cost;
};

class HomePC: public PC
{
public:
    HomePC(string in_operatingSystem,int in_ramSlots,int in_pcieSlots,int in_totalRamSlots, int in_gbPerRam, int in_cpu, int in_ssd, int in_cost, string in_model);

    void Print();
    void Upgrade(){};
private:
    string model;
};
```

and I'm saving the content into the vectors like this:

```
PCList.push_back(new HomePC("MacOS",2,0,1,4,2,256,800,Model));
```

I'm trying to find a way to find a specific Model(for example UserPC) in vector and erase this PC from my list.

Comment: You need a virtual method in your base class and override it in your `HomePC` class, then loop through the vector and call that method to match for a specific model.

Comment: Before doing anything else, your `PC` class needs a virtual destructor.

Comment: The reason for the container of pointers to the base class is so that you should be able to utilize some sort of polymorphism.  Since `model` is not part of the base class, then you need to reconsider your design or your usage of such a container.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a getter for `model`

```
class HomePC: public PC
{
public:
    HomePC(string in_operatingSystem,int in_ramSlots,int in_pcieSlots,int in_totalRamSlots, int in_gbPerRam, int in_cpu, int in_ssd, int in_cost, string in_model);

    void Print();
    void Upgrade(){};
    std::string getModel() const { return model; }
private:
    string model;
};
```

and dynamic cast each element:

```
for (auto pcIt = PCList.cbegin(); pc != PCList.cend(); ++pc) {
    const auto * const homePc = dynamic_cast<HomePC *>(*pcIt);
    if (homePc && homePc->getModel() == "UserPC") {
        PCList.erase(pcIt);
        break;
    }
}
```

You have to add a virtual destructor to `PC` otherwise you can't dynamic cast.

Comment: is this the only way to do something like that?

Comment: @Steiros24 No, of course not. There are many ways to do this. This is the way I would do it.

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise erasing, you can try different ways

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<HomePC>> pileTemp;
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<HomePC>> pileTarget;

std::unique_ptr<HomePC> p1(new HomePC("Windows",2,0,1,4,2,256,800,"UserPC"));

pileTemp.push_back(std::move(p1));

std::unique_ptr<HomePC> p2(new HomePC("MacOs",2,0,1,4,2,256,800,"PCUser"));

pileTemp.push_back(std::move(p2));

std::for_each(pileTemp.begin(), pileTemp.end(), [&](std::unique_ptr<HomePC>& p)->void{ if(p->getmodel() != "UserPC" ) {
                                                             pileTarget.push_back(std::move(p));
                                                                    }
                                                                    });
```

Then, you can clear the temporary container.